# Submitting data from contentscript input to firebase

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore, google-contacts-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am making a chrome extension with a custom popup that comes up after the page is loaded. 
I would like to safe the submitted answers from the input-field to my firebase database, so that i cant include them in another website. It all works, but the problem is, that the answers from the extension get blocked:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type text/plain. See  for more details.

How can i solve this Problem?

Note: I am not a pro at this, so i'd really appreciate an easy to follow solution:)

---

these are my steps:

I downloaded the firebase.js and added it to my manifest.json:

```
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": [  "Libraries/firebase-app.js",
                "Libraries/firebase-firestore.js",
                "sketch.js"],
```

I injected the html to the webpage using the content-script:

```
<div id="bg-modal">
<div class="modal-content">
  <button class="close">+</button>
    <div class="text"></div>

      <form class="antwortfeld antwortfeld1" action="">
          <textarea type="text" name="antwort" placeholder="Antworten"></textarea>
          <button class="Senden">Senden</button>
      </form>
```

I added the firebase app configuration and initialized firebase in the content-script

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...TRZeHhLQ9gMa4V4gy9WSlQ",
  authDomain: "....firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://....firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "....",
  storageBucket: "....appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "...0021",
  appId: "1:385077100021:.....ba5a776b4bc"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();
```

then i added this to the content-script as well to save the inputdata to firebase:

```
const form1 = document.querySelector('.antwortfeld1');


// saving data
form1.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  db.collection('Antworten').add({
    Antwort1: form1.antwort.value,
  })

  form1.antwort.value = ' ';
})
```

As I said, it's all working, but I get blocked. I guess I'll have to use a background-script to get around this? What would that look like?
Any other options?